# How to declare TypeScript array with either strictly strings or strictly objects

Tags: typescript

Here is how I declared it right now:

`displayValues: string[] | {displayName: string}[] = [];`

Then, I use it like this:

```
const value = 'some string';
this.displayValues.push(value);
```

This results in strange error:
const value: string

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & { displayName: string; }'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ displayName: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

Even if I place a type guard `if` statement around the assignment, the error is still there. The very strange part is that Typescript is interpreting my type as `&` not as `|`.

I can fix this simply by doing this: `displayValues: (string | {displayName: string})[] = [];`

However, while this "works", it's an entirely different meaning. It now says that my array can have either one or another type. However, what I want to declare is an array that has either strings or objects, but not both.

Is there a way to do that? Is that possible?

Comment: You need to check if the array is a string array before pushing a string to it (otherwise it could potentially be unsound): https://tsplay.dev/mbQ69N

Comment: The issue seems to be that the initial array initialization seems to ignore the `|` and assume it's both or something. From my trials, it also seems that if I were to initialize the array with either `['test']` or `[{displayName: 'test'}]`, the array gets a permanent stamp of either one type or another.

Comment: In that case, you should use a cast, i.e. `displayValues = [] as (string | ...)[]`.

Comment: No, casting won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, I think, the answer is that, while this is possible, it will not produce the result I am after.

If you think about what this type declaration is saying, it actually makes perfect sense.

It's saying that I want `displayValues` to be either an array of strings or an array of objects, but not contain BOTH at the same time.

Ok, that means, that the second a single value is added to this array, you should NOT be able to treat `displayValues` as a type that can have either strings or objects. It's whatever value it was initialized with.

So, if it was initialized with a string, from then on, its type is an array of strings and if it was initialized with an object, it's an array of objects.

When later in the code, I try to do `displayValues.push('test')`, I am essentially ignoring that reality and saying "keep treating this variable as if it can be still be either at this point", which is not true since I already initialized it.